# Calculate percentage from payments like upwork using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, percentage

I am creating a percentage calculation like upwork use on his own site

the percentage calculation is working fine when I am calculating the percentage from base amount
Percentage is 10%

Let say for base amount `89.00` the percentage value I get is `8.90` and the estimated amount which I will get after deduction is `80.10`

here is the code for this

```
$('txtclientBid').on('input', function() {
    var clientRate = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    var num = parseFloat(clientRate) || 0;
    // $discount_value = ($total / 100) * $percent;
    var val = (num - (num * .1)).toFixed(2);
    var fee= (num /100) * 10;
    $(settings.txtcarrierRate).val(val);
    $('.siteFee').val('-'+fee.toFixed(2))
});
```

but when I calculate the base amount from the estimated amount then I get different values

For example using the same above scenario if I type `80.10` in estimated amount then the percentage value I get is `8.01` and base amount I get is this `88.11`

can some one please tell me why I am getting different values in both cases 
Case 2 is not working fine 
here is my code for this

```
 $('.txtbidderRate').on('input', function() {
        var carrierRate = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0 ;
        var num = parseFloat(carrierRate) || 0;

        var val = (num + (num * .1)).toFixed(2);
        var fee= (num /100) * 10;
        $(settings.txtclientRate).val(val);
        $('.siteFee').val('-'+fee.toFixed(2))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is math.

Say base amount is 100. 10% of 100 = 10. After deduction, 100-10 = 90.

i.e.

```
Estimated Amount = Base Amount - 0.1*Base Amount = 0.9*Base Amount
```

Now consider the other case. You want to get back 100 from the 90 i.e you want to get the base amount from the estimated amount.

So, from the above equation,

```
Base Amount = Estimated Amount/0.9
```

i.e. Base Amount = 90/0.9 = 100.

You are trying to apply the same equation for both the cases - which obviously won't work.

I hope this is what you misunderstood.

So I guess your second `val` should be calculated this way:

```
val = (num/0.9).toFixed(2);
```

EDIT:

Okay let's make things simple. Say you have $89 - this is your base amount. According to what you have written,

```
Estimated Amount = Base Amount - 10% of Base Amount
```

which basically means

```
Estimated Amount = 100% of Base Amount - 10% of Base Amount = 90% of Base Amount
```

So,

```
Estimated Amount = 90% of Base Amount = (90/100)*Base Amount = 0.9*Base Amount
```

Now think the other way round, you have the `Base Amount` and you want the `Estimated Amount`. How would we get it ?

Since `Estimated Amount = 0.9*Base Amount`, we can say `Base Amount = Estimated Amount/0.9` (Dividing both sides by 0.9)

So from your $89,

Estimated Amount = 0.9*89 = $80.1

Now suppose you are given Estimated Amount i.e $80.1, and we need to find Base Amount

We know that `Base Amount = Estimated Amount/0.9` from above, so we have

```
Base Amount = 80.1/0.9 = $89
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please tell me in where i should make changing to my code please for second case

Comment: 0.9 value is not fixed only percentage is fixed which we know is 10% other values will typed by user on input in textbox like base amount and estimated amount so how do i get 0.9 dynamically 
i have tried this
var per = num * .1;
        var val = (num/per).toFixed(2);
but it is giving me 10 in val

i have tried this but

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve but if it is 10% i.e. 0.1 in the first case, we get the second equation from the first one. Equivalently we can write `Base Amount = Estimated Amount/(1-0.1)` it's just the same.

Comment: why are using (1-0.1)  mean why we are subtracting 1 from 0.1

Comment: Thanks @Chintan i really appreciate it